# Make Remote VPS appear like a LAN Device

Tags: networking, router, vpn, lan, vlan

I have a remote VPS with its own public internet IP.

I would like to communicate with the VPS from within my LAN as if it were a LAN device, with a static LAN IP address, and allow the VPS to communicate with my LAN devices via their static LAN addresses. (I think this is called a VLAN?) I would like the VPS to still be accessible through the internet the way it is now.

I *think* that what I need to do is set up a VPN server within my LAN (perhaps on my router itself?) and install a VPN client on the VPS as a secondary network interface. Is this the right path to be going down? Do my true LAN devices also need to connect to the VPN?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a tunnel(VPN) from either your LAN gateway or your end admin device.

You would need an Out of Band Management Connection (OOB or OBM or ILO)
it will be connected to you local network via the VPN

The devil is really in the details. 
Depending on how your gear needs to talk to each other.

What is your end goal for this?

Please upvote if helpful

Comment: i have IP cameras streaming to the VPS, which is an RTMP host. i want to get the cameras themselves off of the internet, streaming to the VPS via LAN, and on the VPS side i want to whitelist the cameras by IP.

Comment: i.e. i don't want my camera hardware to be connected to the internet, and i want them to stream to my rtmp server, but i don't want to physically host the rtmp server.

Comment: ultimately the cameras will be connected to a wifi network which provides LAN connectivity, but no internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I get you. What the "right way" would be is to give you cams a separate network segment.
 Like if your 10.0.0.0/24; put the cams on 10.0.1.0/24. 
The benefit is that you isolate your non cam network, and don't force all your non cam traffic on to te VPN.

The cheap way is to toss a cheapo router in between your cams and LAN, then slap a couple routes in.  your sending everything to your current gateway or the remote VPN end point. Hopefully the internal router will let you host a VPN right to your VPC. but your cloud provider may also provide a VPN termination point in your cloud.
There's a lot of moving parts that aren't built to fit necessarily; then add in (assuming) consumer level gear. 
There will be some trial and error.